# How can I add extra information to Wifi Direct Service discovery responses?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am developing a adhoc app using WiFi direct, and my central node have to
response the "service discovery requests" with the number of people currently connected to it. Currently it only response with SSID and Password.

How can i add this extra information to response frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to add the information into your local service advertising once the number of people changes, just check how you are handling the SSID & Password adding and do the same.

Note that there are caching and delays etc. so the information might not be updated too fast.

Comment: Recently, i have readed that in your blog and i solved my problem. Moreover, I readed the publication in which you explain typical Wi-Fi Direct issues in Android. It helped my so much, thank you for contributing the community!